# Log in with email in symfony2 fosUserBundle

Tags: email, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

How can I enable login with email in symfony2 fosUserBundle? I tried this:

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

But got an error saying the service didn't exist.

Do I have to write my own functionality for this? I thought FosUserBundle came with it out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the 2.x version and not the 1.x version of the user bundle.  Your composer.json should have something like: "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",

You can also check in user-bundle resources security.xml to verify you have the correct version loaded.

The user bundle is a bit frustrating since only 1.0 has been released.  Much of the good stuff is in 2.0 but it is still under development and has been for 2+ years.

Comment: Ah you're saying that the email signin functionality is not part of 1.x but 2.x? In that case I can wait a bit. Also I am using sym2 2.016 so I don't have a composer in my app, still on the deps system. Looking to upgrade soon though.

Comment: Yes.  Only FOSUserBundle 2.x has the email signin.  Not sure when it will be released.  Understand that even S2.1 or higher will still load the UserBundle 1.x.  Might be some time before FOSUserBundle 2.0 is released.  Consider just copy/pasting the functionality.